# Will unsupervised dedupe rules be used in API Contact create?

Tags: drupal, api, developer

I want to import an old database using API Contact create. In the de-dupe rule documentation it mentions "They are also used when you Import contacts". I see in the API documentation that there exists a parameter 'dupe_check'. When set what will it do exactly? Will it use the rules? How will it respond when dupes are found?

Answer (score 2):

The `dupe_check` works almost exactly the opposite from what you'd expect :)

If you set `dupe_check` to `TRUE` in a `Contact.create` API call, then an unsupervised dedupe check will be performed.  If there IS a duplicate, then the contact won't be updated, the API call will return an error with a list of contact IDs that are matched.

Comment: Wow a 6 year old question now answered!